# how to call my service in angular using setInterval

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

I have a service which gets returns some data at the page load,

```
getAllTurbinesStat(){
  return this.http.get(this.url_stat_Turbines_all);
}
```

in my component I consume this service:

```
this.service.getAllTurbinesStat().subscribe( s => {
   this.allStats.push(s);
});
```

allStat is an array, now every 3 minutes this function should be run to update data, should setInterval be in service or in my component? And how should I write it? Because the first time I don't need the setinterval, because once the page loaded first time, my data is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

First create one function in your component like this.

```
getAllTurbinesStat() {
  this.service.getAllTurbinesStat().subscribe(s => {
    this.allStats.push(s);
  });
}
```

And then in from `ngOnInit()` or from `constructor` of your component use this.

```
this.getAllTurbinesStat();
setInterval(() => this.getAllTurbinesStat(), 180000);
```

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same solution. The "trick" is just to call it once before creating the interval.

Comment: Also, OP wanted to call the function after `3minutes`. Which is `180000ms` not `30000ms` :)

Comment: the getAllTurbinesStat() inside setinterval in ngonInit gives this error :

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): Timeout', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(handler: TimerHandler, timeout?: number, ...arguments: any[]): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimerHandler'.ts(2769)

Comment: try this: `setInterval(() => this.getAllTurbinesStat(), 180000);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use interval for that like below:

in you service

```
 getAllTurbinesStat(){
  return this.http.get(this.url_stat_Turbines_all);
 }

 getData(): {
   return interval(3000).pipe(
      switchMap( () => this.getAllTurbinesStat())
   )

 }
```

in your component

```
this.service.getData().subscribe( s => {
   this.allStats.push(s);
});
```

Comment: in my component you are calling getData() which takes 3000msc to run right?i want first it runs on page load not after 3000msc

Comment: interval will generate event every 3minutes, this event will call ````this.getAllTurbinesStat()``` and you will get new data every three minutes in your component

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer from rxjs.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
​
/*
  timer takes a second argument, how often to emit subsequent values
  in this case we will emit first value after 0 second and subsequent
  values every 3 minutes after
*/
const source = timer(0, 180000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5......
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

For you case.

```
  return timer(0, 180000).pipe(
      flatMap( () => this.getAllTurbinesStat())
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

First call your function one time in the `ngOnInit` of your component then get on with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
ngOnInit() {
   getAllTurbinesStat();
   setInterval(getAllTurbinesStat(), 3000);
}

getAllTurbinesStat() {
  return this.http.get(this.url_stat_Turbines_all);
}
```